# Firebase Verify with E-Mail and Phone

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

For a certain area I want to have my user registred and verified with BOTH:

his EMAIL adress and  his PHONE NUMBER. After email and phone was verified, I link the EMAIL to the PHONE with these lines of code:

```
 mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        if(config.debugcode) {Log.e("LINKING successful",user.toString());
                            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("locked", false).apply();
```

Now Firebase gives me the possibility to check if the EMAIL was verified with the following code:
           `if (user.isEmailVerified()) { }`

But how can I check, if my User with the LINKED Credential (EMAIL to PHONE) has BOTH of it verified?

Comment: Did my answer prove helpful to you, @LosKayos ?

Comment: No, because: I want to check if my User has verified his EMAIL and PHONE Number, so to get the access to the area he has to confirm his email adress (the code works and is already written) and his phone number (which also works) before he can access a certain area. Now I need to check if BOTH was verified (I edit my question now to make that more clear)

Comment: see the updated answer, @LosKayos

Comment: to obtain the `credential` of phone auth here  `mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)` , you have to first authenticate user with phone auth which makes phone number already verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification()` and `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()`

This can let you know whether the email has been verified or not. Read more about email and phone authentication in Firebase, [here.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj9g-CA55TeAhUC-qQKHQKCAkoQFjAOegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fauth%2Fandroid%2Femail-link-auth&usg=AOvVaw1eWjj9GvcX5OoDqweTdsIx)

Also visit, [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#9.6) to know more about how to use this feature.

**UPDATE**

The above code helps you identify if the user has verified the email or not, but currently there's no method to find if the user has got his phone number verified.

For this you have to do it manually, what you can do is that when you you verify OTP and let user login with phone number, you can update a node in Json, with boolean value 'true` that tells you, that user has got his number verified.

Now to see which user has his phone number verified, you can run a code like this:

```java
DatabaseRef userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getRef("users");
userRef.orderByChild("phoneVerified").equalTo(true).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

     if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
        //it means user already registered
        //Add code to show your prompt
        showPrompt();
     }else{
        //It is new users
        //write an entry to your user table
        //writeUserEntryToDB();
     }
}
```

Comment: Well that was my second thought to do it with a DB-entry. Thank you for the Code, but when I set this manually over my App, during registration it's set by default to "false" and while linking (Email to phone) I set this variable to "true" - isn't this a possible gate? I mean, when someone modifies my code and sets this variable to "true" as default... they can jump the reg-process. Right?

Comment: Well hypothetically speaking, this is possible but, so is any other possibility of someone changing your code and entering in your app or database. This problem is NOT actually a thing to worry about if you strictly monitor your Firebase database rules and your android code from time to time.

Comment: I know this is offtopic, but any suggestions for the Database rules for this kind / case of intrusion?

Comment: This is fully based on which users you should give permission to write and which you should not, who can read from your database and which could write on your database, which user can change some data and which can introduce some new data, if you keep in mind and provide the most necessary permission to the users, it would not be any problem. Also know that Firebase itself is very secure as it is. You can read more about it here,https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: @LosKayos if you found something useful from this, consider marking the answer as correct and upvoting it, I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Comment: Done that, thank you for your patience! Will get to the FB DB soon!

Comment: Great, glad to hear that. Cheers!